# Struct to it's ReadOnlyMemory<byte> representation

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.memory

I have following struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct Message
{
     int Header;
     int Data;
}
```

and I want to send it over the wire, without allocations (using `SendAsync(ReadOnlyMemory<byte>)`) call.

How can I get the `Memory<byte>` from given struct?

I ended up in having `Span<byte>`, and then got stuck.

```
var message = new Message {
  Header = 1, Data = 3
};
var bytes = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(
    MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpan(ref message, 1)
);
```

Is there any way how to put the struct directly into stream without any allocations?

I'm on `netcoreapp2.1`.

Comment: Spans can only live on the stack. An asynchronous method needs its parameter to live at least as long as the task itself. Therefore, how can you ensure that the span does live to the end of the task? You can't, hence why those method use Memory<T>, which can live longer. Which means you'll need to copy it anyway.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel my `message` is captured in the AsyncStateMachine anyway - it is not `ref struct`.

Comment: Anyway, the title is misleading. I'll update it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
Span<Message> valSpan = stackalloc Message[1];
valSpan[0] = new Message { Header = 123, Data = 456 };
Span<byte> bytes = MemoryMarshal.Cast<Message, byte>(valSpan); // has length 8
```

Note I'm using `Span<T>` here. You can do mostly the same stuff with `Memory<T>` if needed - but you need a backing array or similar, which will usually require an allocation - if not of the array, then of a custom `MemoryManager<T>`:

```
var arr = new Message[1];
arr[0] = new Message { Header = 123, Data = 456 };
Memory<byte> bytes = MemoryMarshal.Cast<Message, byte>(arr); // has length 8
```

---

Essentially, you are very close here:

```
MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpan(ref message, 1)
```

The trick, though, is to use `MemoryMarshal.Cast<TFrom, byte>(...)` to get a a span of bytes.

Comment: Nice, but is there any way to do the same if `Message` contains a reference or pointer like field? let's say a `byte[] data`

Comment: @joe you can convert ref-containing data to bytes (some of which will be basically meaningless - i.e. the references/pointers), but you can't go back again - basically, the runtime and CLR **really** doesn't want you creating non-zero references that are invalid - it would violate an entire family of assumptions. You of course *can* do it with unsafe code, but .... please don't

Comment: ♦ Why is it meaningless? In many case I have a struct with `int` and `byte[]` `object` inside and I want a Memory from it (the memory should keept the reference/pointer instead of the data itself). But I can't do ref->data bytes in this case.[Cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.cast?view=netcore-2.2) does not allow me to do so. It cannot cotain reference or pointers. I understand that we shouldn't go back. But why do we have this go forward limit?

Comment: @joe references are just pointers with semantic meaning, but... still just random-ish numbers that will change each run *or during runs if the GC chooses*, and cannot be usefully interpreted; here's the code that shows doing exactly this, so it is possible - just... not useful: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/0914818c0f1db594a5e75c631128fe77

Comment: @joe note I did have to drop to `unsafe` code to get back as a span; you *can* do it without, though - https://gist.github.com/mgravell/1e65d60e8c21b0de18137fa39688fe25